# How to merge two text files and convert it to csv file in Scala

Tags: scala, csv

I use the following code to export a `DataFrame` :

```
df.select("A", "b", "C", "D","E")
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .save("newiris.csv")
```

I get two text files as following :

*part-00000*

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
```

*part-00001*

```
6.7,3,5,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
```

Now I want to have them combined to one file like

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
6.7,3,5,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
```

And then convert it to CSV. How can I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary Scala bits here are `scala.io.Source` to read the file and get the lines, `++` to append `part0-00000` and `part-00001`, and a `foreach` loop to go through the combined data and write to a file. File I/O is the same as in Java.

```
scala> import java.io._

scala> import scala.io.Source

scala> val part0 = Source.fromFile("part-00000.txt").getLines
part0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val part1 = Source.fromFile("part-00001.txt").getLines
part1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val part2 = part0.toList ++ part1.toList
part2: List[String] = List(5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa, 4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa, 4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa, 4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa, 5,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa, 5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa, 6.7,3,5,1.7,Iris-versicolor, 6,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor, 5.7,2.6,3.5,1,Iris-versicolor, 5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor, 5.5,2.4,3.7,1,Iris-versicolor, 5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor)

scala> val part00002 = new File("part-00002")
part00002: java.io.File = part-00002

scala> val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(part00002))
bw: java.io.BufferedWriter = java.io.BufferedWriter@56826a75

scala> part2.foreach(p => bw.write(p + "\n"))


scala> bw.close
```

Inspect the file:

```
brian:/tmp/ $ cat part-00002                                                            
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
6.7,3,5,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
```

Comment: Thanks so much! When I do val part00002 = new File("part-00002") I got an error not found:type File. do I need to define File or import something?

Comment: `import java.io._` should do it.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect. One more question, will this operation be easier if the part-00000 and part-00001are in csv format?

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your help. In this example can I read part-00000 into part00002 first and then read part-00001 into part00002 to extend part00002 not overwriting it.